# Kinect V2, HDFace sample - 0x80070002 - Error File not found

Tags: c#, c++, image-processing, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to work with `HDFace` of `Kinect V2`.

By default there is no plain `C++` sample, but I managed to find it [here](https://github.com/UnaNancyOwen/Kinect2Sample/tree/master/Sample/HDFace)

Compilation goes smoothly. But at run time, I get error 0x80070002 in `hResult` at the following point:

```
hResult = CreateHighDefinitionFaceFrameSource( pSensor, &pHDFaceSource[count] );
if( FAILED( hResult ) )
{
        std::cerr << "Error : CreateHighDefinitionFaceFrameSource()" << std::endl;
        return -1;
}
```

Of course, I searched around and found that I should include

```
xcopy "$(KINECTSDK20_DIR)Redist\Face\$(Platform)\NuiDatabase" "$(TargetDir)\NuiDatabase" /S /R /Y /I
```

in my `Post-Build Event`.

But still I am getting the same error. Is anyone familiar with the issue?

btw, I performed rebuild after adding thing in my `Post-Build Event`.

I also checked that `NuiDatabase` folder is present in the `/64/debug` folder.

I also checked `HD Face Basics WPF sample` which ships with `Kinect SDK`, it works perfectly. In `WPF project's bin` folder, there is additional file named `Microsoft.Kinect.Face.xml`. I copy pasted it in my projects's /64/Debug`, but to no avail.

pl help..